# AngularJS Directive Isolate scope behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working through some tutorials trying to firm up my grasp of isolate scope and I'm having some issues. I get the high concept but I'm trying to justify some behavior I'm seeing that I don't understand. At a high level the way I understand it, the options attached work like this:

@ - allows you to feed in a string
& - provides one way data binding
= - provides two way data binding

So considering the following code:

```
<div ng-app="choreApp">
  <div ng-controller="ChoreCtrl">
    <kid done="logChore(chore)"></kid>
  </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('choreApp', []);

app.controller("ChoreCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.logChore = function(chore){
    alert(chore + " is done!");
  };
});

app.directive("kid", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
     scope: {
        done: "&"
     },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="chore">' +
      '{{chore}}' +
      '<div class="button" ng-click="done({chore: chore})">I\'m done</div>'
  };
});
```

The above is wired up ok, with the '&' the logChore function works, all is well.

The '@' doesn't work, as expected, since it is just reading in a string, when I click nothing happens.

However, I also expect '=' to work ok since it's just a two way binding, however what actually happens is the function executes three times without any action on my part (the click), then is seems to function as normal. Why does the function execute three times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use two way binding ("=") with `done="logChore(chore)"`, **the results of calling `logChore(chore)`** are assigned to `done` - **not the function itself** (as `&` does).

So every time Angular calls `$watch` to see if anything it's watching has changed the function `logChore(chore)` is called.  Because of dirty checking `$watch` often evaluates the watch list multiple times per `$digest` loop- that's why you saw 3 executions (and you'd see more any time something happens that triggers a `$digest`).

In order to pass the function itself in when using `=` you can do this:

```
<kid done="logChore"></kid>
```

And change you template to pass in chore like so:

```
ng-click="done(chore)"
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7csNN/) of that working.

Also, rather than thinking of `@` as passing in a string I'd think of it more broadly as one-way data binding.  It's one-way because a change on the parent scope will be reflected inside the directive, but a change in the directive's isolate scope won't be reflected in the parent.